# How to properly validate JSON Forms in React on submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, frontend, jsonforms

I am currently working on a project, which involves using [JSON Forms](https://jsonforms.io/)
I have a problem regarding validation. The reason is that there are multiple values in inputs and some of them should not exceed or fall behind exact numbers (minimum and maximum fields). How to make my code work so one won't be able to submit form if values don't meet min or max requirements? Without writing a long function and parsing through json schema, because it is too huge?

Example schema: `

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "sample1",
    "sample2",
    "sample3",
    "sample4"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "sample1": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "sample2": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "sample3": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "price": {
          "minimum": 10,
          "maximum": 100
        },
        "price2": {
          "type": "number",
          "minimum": 5,
          "maximum": 1000
        },
        "price3": {
          "type": "number",
          "minimum": 10,
          "maximum": 100
        },
        "price4": {
          "type": "number",
          "minimum": 9,
          "maximum": 12
        },
        "cargo": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "values": {
              "type": "number",
              "minimum": 500,
              "maximum": 1000
            },
            "values2": {
              "type": "number",
              "minimum": 5,
              "maximum": 10
            }
          }
        },
        "cars": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "prices": {
              "type": "number",
              "minimum": 10000,
              "maximum": 20000
            }
          }
        },
        "trucks": {
          "type": "integer",
          "minimum": 10,
          "maximum": 100
        },
        "fields": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "place": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "price10": {
                "type": "number",
                "minimum": 0.5,
                "maximum": 1.5
              },
              "sales": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "discount": {
                      "type": "integer",
                      "minimum": 10,
                      "maximum": 90,
                      "default": 0
                    },
                    "price76": {
                      "type": "number",
                      "minimum": 10,
                      "maximum": 20,
                      "default": 0.1
                    },
                    "price69": {
                      "type": "number",
                      "minimum": 30,
                      "maximum": 40,
                      "default": 0.1
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "sample4": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "price": {
          "minimum": 10,
          "maximum": 100
        },
        "price1": {
          "type": "number",
          "minimum": 0,
          "maximum": 100
        },
        "price2": {
          "type": "number",
          "minimum": 0,
          "maximum": 1
        },
        "price3": {
          "type": "number",
          "minimum": 90,
          "maximum": 100
        },
        "garbage": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "price55": {
              "type": "number",
              "minimum": 5,
              "maximum": 10
            },
            "price85": {
              "type": "number",
              "minimum": 5,
              "maximum": 10
            }
          }
        },
        "web": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "landing": {
              "type": "number",
              "minimum": 2,
              "maximum": 3
            }
          }
        },
        "observer": {
          "type": "integer",
          "minimum": 80,
          "maximum": 500
        },
        "mountains": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "rock": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "km": {
                "type": "number",
                "minimum": 500,
                "maximum": 600
              },
              "sales": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "discount": {
                      "type": "integer",
                      "minimum": 10,
                      "maximum": 90,
                      "default": 0
                    },
                    "price99": {
                      "type": "number",
                      "minimum": 1,
                      "maximum": 2,
                      "default": 0.1
                    },
                    "price100": {
                      "type": "number",
                      "minimum": 5,
                      "maximum": 10,
                      "default": 0.1
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`

I tried to look for answers on JSON forms docs, but there are just basics validation examples. The reason is that errors occur on render, but still I am able to submit my form even having these errors.

Comment: so please do explain some things - what language are you using to parse this? what libs are you using etc  - it might be easier for ppl to answer - cheers!

Comment: I use JavaScript and React library